# Are there any client-side mitigations for FREAK?

Tags: tls

While we wait for patches to address the TLS FREAK vulnerability, is there anything relatively straight forward on the client-side that can be done to mitigate the risk in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Use a TLS stack which is not affected. The problem lies deep in the stack and there is no magic switch like `NOFREAK=1` to disable to bug.

If you cannot switch the TLS stack or use the available fixes against the current stack (at least for OpenSSL) you might try to put some SSL-intercepting proxy in front which does all the TLS for you. Of course these kind of proxies often have their own problems, like not validating the certificates properly.

Comment: Are there any SSL intercepting proxies that a clever end user can install on, say, their home router? I have some old Android and Kindle devices that have fairly broken TLS stacks. Obviously I would want something that validated certificates properly and forwarded information about invalid certificates to the end device.

Comment: The only SSL intercepting proxies I'm aware of are either commercial and integrated in firewalls or more for testing (like mitmproxy). I don't know if any of the latter could be put on a home router and I'm sure it depends a lot on how open and capable the router is. But of course you could setup such a proxy on any computer and point to it, it does not need to be the router.